# Is the complement of an open ball in a Banach space connected?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be a real Banach Space whose dimension is at least $2$, and let $S$ be a subset of $B$ that is an open ball. Is the complement of $S$ (with respect to $B$) always connected?

---

#### Idea

One could then perhaps make use of the facts that every $2$-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to the Euclidean plane and that - for the Euclidean plane - my question has an obvious "YES" answer (since every open ball is the interior of a circle).

Comment: Do Bananach spaces have slippery peels?

Comment: Yes, it is.  What's your plan for proving it, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it suffices to prove this for two dimensional sub-spaces of B. We would want to consider those sub-spaces of B containing any 2 linearly independent "vectors" of B which "originate" at the center of S and "terminate" outside S. One could then perhaps make use of the facts that every 2-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to the Euclidean plane and that-for the Euclidean plane-my question has an obvious "YES" answer (since every open ball is the interior of a circle).

Answer (score 3):

#### Two-dimensional case

Let $C$ be a circle enclosing the ball $S$. For each point $p\in S$, consider the line through $p$ and the center of $S$. A segment of this line connects $p$ to $C$. Since $C$ itself is path-connected, $B\setminus S$ is path-connected.

#### General case

Given $p,q\notin S$, apply the above to   a two-dimensional affine space containing $p,q$, and the center of $S$.